# What are the possible causes of a curl protocol error?

Tags: ssl, squid, curl, consul

I'm getting the following error with curl:

```
# curl -vvvv https://192.168.99.100:8501/ui
*   Trying 192.168.99.100...
* Connected to 192.168.99.100 (192.168.99.100) port 8501 (#0)
* WARNING: using IP address, SNI is being disabled by the OS.
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 192.168.99.100:-9825
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 192.168.99.100:-9825
```

When I read the accounts of others - [they say there are three possible causes](http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html):

1. The Destination Site Does Not Like the Protocol
2. The Destination Site Does Not Like the Cipher ([SSLv3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26482202/15441) issue)
3. The SSL Private cert Has Expired
4. A [Curl bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1319/)

Now I've checked these four - and am still getting the error - so there must be a fourth reason. My question is: **What are the possible causes of a curl protocol error?**

I'm guessing I'll have to turn SSL trace on - but I'm trying to avoid having to do that.

(Note that this is also having issues talking to a squid proxy).

Comment: Did you try anything else like a browser, wget, etc...? Try `nmap -p 8501 --script ssl-enum-ciphers 192.168.99.100`.

Comment: "..Now I've checked these four ..." - how did you check? Can you access this URL using the browser or some other tool? Did you have a look at possible error messages on the server side?

Comment: "The SSL Private Key Has Expired" - A key has no expiration date and thus cannot expire. A certificate (which includes the *public* key) can expire.

Comment: will do - thanks for the request for clarification...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar errors ("NSS error -5938" and "curl: (35) SSL connect error") when curling the Consul download zip file (https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/0.6.4/consul_0.6.4_linux_amd64.zip).

Updating the NSS package fixed the issue.

`yum update nss.x86_64`